# Email & Phone already exists check - codeigniter (Model & Controller)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, unique, codeigniter-3

I have been creating API for Mobile App. My Task is to check whether email / phone no already exists. If so i should display the error as "Already Exist".

**../models/Model_api.php**

```
public function customer_email_check($customer_email){

    $customer_email = $this->input->post('customer_email');
    $this->db->where('customer_email', $customer_email);
    $result = $this->db->get('customers_info');

    if($result->num_rows() > 0){
        /*
         * the email already exists
         * */
        return false;
    }
}
    
public function customer_phoneno_check($customer_phone_no){

    $customer_phone_no = $this->input->post('customer_phone_no');
    $this->db->where('customer_phone_no', $customer_phone_no);
    $result = $this->db->get('customers_info');

    if($result->num_rows() > 0){
        /*
         * the phone already exists
         * */
        return false;
    }
}
```

**../controllers/Api.php**

```
public function customer_register_api(){ 

            $path = $_FILES['customer_image']['name'];
            $path_tmp = $_FILES['customer_image']['tmp_name'];

            $final_name = $path;
                move_uploaded_file( $path_tmp, './public/images/customers/'.$final_name );
   
    
            $customer_name = $_POST['customer_name'];    
            $customer_image = $final_name;     
            $customer_address = $_POST['customer_address'];  
            $customer_city = $_POST['customer_city'];     
            $customer_state = $_POST['customer_state']; 
            $customer_pincode = $_POST['customer_pincode']; 
            $customer_phone_no = $_POST['customer_phone_no']; 
            $customer_email = $_POST['customer_email']; 
            $customer_password = md5($_POST['customer_password']); 
            $status = $_POST['status'];

            //$existent_phoneno = $this->Model_api->existent_phoneno($this->input->post('customer_phone_no'));
            //$existent_email = $this->Model_api->existent_email($this->input->post('customer_email'));
            $customer_email_check = $this->Model_api->customer_email_check();
            $customer_phoneno_check = $this->Model_api->customer_phoneno_check();

    if(!$customer_name || !$customer_image || !$customer_address || !$customer_city || !$customer_state || !$customer_pincode || !$customer_phone_no || !$customer_email || !$customer_password || !$status){ 
       //$this->response("Enter complete Product information to save", 400); 
        echo json_encode (
                    array(
                        "status"=>'false',
                        "error"=>'All Fields are Mandatory',
                    ));

    }elseif ($customer_email_check === 1) {
    //elseif (!empty($existent_phoneno) || ($existent_email)) {
                echo json_encode (
                    array(
                        "status"=>'false',
                        "error"=>'Email Already Exists',
                    ));
    }elseif ($customer_phoneno_check === 1) {
    //elseif (!empty($existent_phoneno) || ($existent_email)) {
                echo json_encode (
                    array(
                        "status"=>'false',
                        "error"=>'Phone Already Exists',
                    ));
    }else{ 
        $result = $this->Model_api->add_customer(array("customer_name"=>$customer_name, "customer_image"=>$customer_image, "customer_address"=>$customer_address, "customer_city"=>$customer_city, "customer_state"=>$customer_state, "customer_pincode"=>$customer_pincode, "customer_phone_no"=>$customer_phone_no, "customer_email"=>$customer_email, "customer_password"=>$customer_password, "status"=>$status)); 
        if($result === 0){ 
                echo json_encode (
                    array(
                     "status"=>'false',
                      //"Seller Details"=>$query->result(),
                    ));
       }else{
            //$this->response("success", 200); 
        echo json_encode (
                    array(
                        "status"=>'true',
                        "message"=>'Customer Registered Successfully',
                        //"Seller Details"=>$result->result(),
                    ));
        }
         }
}
```

if the functions customer_phoneno_check & customer_email_check at Model_Api.php returns false i need to show the response saying already exist which is at ../controllers/Api.php using function customer_register_api()

Table : customers_info
Keys  : customer_email & customer_phone_no

Comment: Side note: you should add a unique key if you dont have it on email and phone in the table otherwise it is race conditions waiting to happen .

Comment: @RaymondNijland actually i had unique key at db table but here at API for mobile app needs to check them from db and show email / phone already exists. As of now when i post already existing email or phone it throws error.